# How to disable the "Show Tab Bar" option in a macOS Catalyst App

Tags: swift, xcode, mac-catalyst

I have a macOS Catalyst app that supports multiple windows, but it has built in tabs, and that's why I would like to disable the native Menu Bar's "Show Tab Bar" option.

As you can see on the image below, it's actually breaking my layout, and since my app will never use this feature I would like to get rid of it, is there a way to do this?

[image: Unnecessary tab bar]

Here's the option I would like to completely disable:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution I was given by an Apple developer last summer, which calls an AppKit method to disable tabs and the menu items:

```
Class _nswindow = NSClassFromString(@"NSWindow");
[_nswindow setAllowsAutomaticWindowTabbing:NO];
```

You need to do the ugly NSClassFtomString thing because AppKit is not available in Catalyst, but it’s okay to ship an app that does this (I do).

Oh and that’s Objective-C not Swift, obviously. Calling “private” API from Swift is tricky; I recommend either bridging to use ObjC or using the [Dynamic library](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic) like so: `Dynamic.NSWindow.setAllowsAutomaticWindowTabbing(false)`.

Answer (score 2):

With Mac OS Monterey you can use the Window tab opt-out in `Info.plist` called `UIApplicationSupportsTabbedSceneCollection`

```xml
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest-macos</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsTabbedSceneCollection</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```

Source - [WWDC 21 Presentation: What's new in Mac Catalyst (@7:45)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10052/)

Comment: I'm not sure what the "-macos" is doing here, but adding `UIApplicationSupportsTabbedSceneCollection` with a `false` value under the `UIApplicationSceneManifest` key in my Info.plist achieved the desired result.

Comment: `-macos` is restricting the scope of this scene manifest to when running under macOS. This is useful when you build a single app targeting both iOS and Mac (Designed for iPad) and need a different configuration for each OS.

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for the answer in an AppKit app. Turns out you can do this in a Storyboard by selecting your `NSWindow` instance and setting this value:

[image: Properties for NSWindow showing "Tabbing Mode" set to "Disallowed"]

Here, set "Tabbing Mode" to "Disallowed" and those menu items (and that capability) are gone.

And of course, you can do this in code as well:

`window.tabbingMode = .disallowed`